# How to get generic argument name via reflection

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

given generic class

```
class Foo<TData> { }
```

and concrete type

```
var type = typeof(Foo<string>) //Fpp`[System.String]
var genericType = type.GetGenericTypeDefinition(); //Foo`1[TData]
```

I would like to get "TData". Or the other way: Get the value of the generic argument based on generic argument name:

```
GetGenericArgumentType(typeof(Foo<string>), "TData") //should return System.String
```

Comment: If it has just one argument.
    
    type.GetGenericArguments()[0].FullName

Comment: It returns System.String not TData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's feasible with the following: (this is just for demonstration, it assumes that the type is generic, and the parameter name do exist)

```
public string GetGenericArgumentType(Type type, string paramName)
{

    var genericType = type.GetGenericTypeDefinition(); 

    var genericParam = genericType
        .GetGenericArguments()
        .Select((t, i) => new { Index = i, t.Name })
        .First(arg => arg.Name == paramName);

    return type.GetGenericArguments()[genericParam.Index].Name;
}

class GenericFoo<TData, TSecondData> { }

public void GetGenericArgumentTypeTest()
{
    string name1 = this.GetGenericArgumentType(
                        typeof(GenericFoo<string, int>), "TData"); //String
    string name2 = this.GetGenericArgumentType(
                        typeof(GenericFoo<string, int>), "TSecondData"); //Int32
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, based on this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericparameterconstraints(v=vs.110).aspx

```
Type def = typeof(Foo<>);
Type[] defparams = def.GetGenericArguments();
Console.WriteLine(defParams[0].Name); // writes "TData"
Console.WriteLine(defParams[0].GenericParameterPosition); // writes 0

Type concreteDef = typeof(Foo<string>)
Type[] concreteDefParams = concreteDef.GetGenericArguments();
Console.WriteLine(concreteDefParams[0].FullName); // writes "System.String"
```